# ArgumentResolverTrait not found in Definition.php on line 14

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We duplicated a website from one domain to another. We solved MySQL and FTP. Everything is fine, but the new site won't load because of this error:

Website - bombabox.de

> Fatal error: Trait 'Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\League\Container\Argument\ArgumentResolverTrait' not found in /data/web/virtuals/280372/virtual/www/domains/bombabox.de/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/lib/packages/League/Container/Definition/Definition.php on line 14

This way is correct according to the new hosting `/data/web/virtuals/280372/virtual/www/domains/bombabox.de/`

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\League\Container\Definition;

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\League\Container\Argument\{
    ArgumentResolverInterface, ArgumentResolverTrait, ClassNameInterface, RawArgumentInterface
};
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Vendor\League\Container\ContainerAwareTrait;
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionException;

class Definition implements ArgumentResolverInterface, DefinitionInterface
{
    use ArgumentResolverTrait;
    use ContainerAwareTrait;
```

line 14: use ArgumentResolverTrait;

[Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-lib-packages-league-container-definition-definition.html)

I'd be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

We've already solved the problem. We had to delete woocommerce plugin from FTP and upload "clean" version again.

Now everything is running.